# Is there a way to make my Windows know about my BIOS settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios

For a very specific situation on a project, I need to make a Windows machine know about some specific settings at the BIOS(such as Enabled/Disabled PXE boot, Boot Sequence, Bios Version, and more....). I'm thinking in doing this with powershell, VBScript, or whatever(actually doesn't matter how, I just need to read these settings from Windows).

I'm reseaching this and found nothing for now, there is a way(maybe a indirect one)?

Comment: BIOS version can be found with `systeminfo | findstr BIOS` in the command prompt. I imagine other settings would be somewhat BIOS specific, i.e. depending on the brand/version.

Comment: I found a lot of settings at regedit->HKLM\HardwarezDescription\System\BIOS. However, it have just Bios Version too.

Comment: WMI can read much of this too.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394077(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @uSlackr - Actually only BIOS version too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal way to do this without using Manufacturer specific tools per motherboard (I do know HP has a dll that adds a lot of methods the `Root\HP\InstrumentedBIOS` namespace in WMI that gets included with thier BIOS setup software. See [this pdf](http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/cmi_whitepaper.pdf) starting at page 9).

You may have some luck with Windows' [native WMI calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), however the data you are looking for could only be stored in the 40:63 range of the `BiosCharacteristics` array, and that data is vendor specific.

You could attempt to build a database of popular vendors and either bundle their dll's or use the WMI calls with windows and try to decode those reserved values. But other than those two choices, there is no other real option.